# Update Foreign Key based on condition across both tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

Let's say I have a custom fields table, and that custom fields can be grouped into groups. Lets also say I have a groups table.

Let's also say I have a convention whereby the prefix of the name of a custom field should be groupName_ where groupName is the title column of the groups table.

How can I update a large number of existing custom fields to take the group id in SQL? I've tried this:

```
UPDATE fields, fgroup
SET group_id = fgroup.id
WHERE name LIKE 'gp1\_%' AND SUBSTRING(name, 0, 4)) = lower(title) AND fields.account_id=fgroup.account_id AND fields.account_id = 111;
```

This fails because update does not take multiple tables.

How can I do this for a list of group names (gp1, gp2, gp3, gp4)? How could I also modify the prefix length? (not always `SUBSTRING(name, 0, 4)`, but a populated third parameter based on the length of the prefix until first underscore?

Comment: Please, *always* provide actual table definitions with a question like that. `CREATE TABLE` statements or the output of `\d tbl` in psql, as well as your version of Postgres. And add table-qualification to all columns so we know what table they are supposed to reference. Ideally also some sample data and the desired outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query looks like SQL-Server or MySQL syntax. In Postgres you can only update a single table in a single statement. Join in additional tables with a `FROM` clause. [Details in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-update.html)

For a **single group** (with some guesswork where each column belongs to)

```
UPDATE fields f
SET    group = g.id
FROM   fgroup g
WHERE  f.name LIKE 'gp1\_%'
AND    left(f.name, 4) = lower(g.title)
AND    f.account_id = 111
AND    f.account_id = g.account_id;
```

For **multiple groups** and a, quote: `populated third parameter based on the length of the prefix`, let's name it `prefix_len`:

```
UPDATE fields f
SET    group = g.id
FROM   fgroup g
WHERE  left(f.name, prefix_len) = ANY '{gp1,gp2,gp3,gp4}'::text[]
AND    left(f.name, prefix_len) = lower(g.title)
AND    f.account_id = 111
AND    f.account_id = g.account_id;
```

Aside: [`group` is a reserved word](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html), don't use it as identifier.